# Subtracting expressions with radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I want to subtract the expressions $20\sqrt{72a^3b^4c} - 14\sqrt{8a^3b^4c}$. I simplified this to $120ab^2\sqrt{2ac}-28ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$. My textbook says the answer is $92ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$. Why doesnt the $ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$ part change at all? I thought everything except the 92 would cancel out since it looks like it's cancelling out. This is my first time using stackexchange, please tell me if I can ask this question better. Thanks.

Comment: Just view $ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$ as a separate entity. As a matter of fact, let us use $d$ to represent it. Then, we would have $120d-28d$, which is clearly $92d$.

Comment: Sorry, I was terrible at math in school and am teaching myself from the ground up, and my google-fu is failing me here. My question is how all the variables don't change, and especially the $\sqrt{2}$ , since my intuition (obv. wrongly) tells me it (and the variables) should cancel out. I assume it's because if the variable is a negative subtracting them wouldn't equal 0, but that doesn't explain the radical to me.

Comment: Do you understand that 120k-28k = 92k?

Comment: Only if you say so. Why wouldn't the k get cancelled?

Comment: Alright. Let's start with smaller numbers, how do we know that 5k-3k = 2k? Actually, 5k just means $5\times k$, and the $\times$ sign is hidden. So, $5k$ is actually $k+k+k+k+k$, and $3k$ is $k+k+k$, and $2k$ is $k+k$. Now, can you see that 5k-3k=2k?

Comment: Please, [come to the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) and let's not use the comment section as a teaching platform.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I need 20 reputation to post there. That explanation makes a lot of sense, I think you using k instead of x made it harder for me to understand, just not used to these kinds of abstract concepts. The only part that confuses me now is the fact that the square root of 2 seems like it should be a constant, so you would actually subtract it from itself, like $\sqrt{2ac}-\sqrt{2ac}$ seems like it should just equal $\sqrt{ac}$, how does that work?

Comment: No, $\sqrt{2ac}-\sqrt{2ac}$ is exactly $0$.

Comment: However, $(2\sqrt{2ac})-(\sqrt{2ac})$ equals $\sqrt{2ac}$.

Comment: This is because $2\sqrt{2ac}$ actually means $2\times\sqrt{2ac}$, which would be expanded as $\sqrt{2ac}+\sqrt{2ac}$. Then, $2\sqrt{2ac}-\sqrt{2ac}=(\sqrt{2ac}+\sqrt{2ac})-\sqrt{2ac}=\sqrt{2ac}$

Comment: Okay, I'm just going to try and digest all this and will ask another question if I need to, don't want to congest the comments. Thanks for all your help Kenny!

Comment: The distrubutive law of mult. over add. is $AC + BC = (A+B)C$  In your case, $A = 120$, $B = -28$, and $C = ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$.

Comment: @Patrick When something is written as $a * b$ it means that we have to add $b$, $a$ times or $a$, $b$ times. Eg, $2 * 3$ equals $2 + 2 + 2 = 6$ or $3 + 3 = 6$.This is same as exponents like $a^b$ means that $a$ is multiplied by itself $b$ times.

Comment: @Patrick Lets take your expression, $120ab^2\sqrt{2ac} - 28ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$. First part $120ab^2\sqrt{2ac} $ means that we have to add $ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$ to itself 120 times, same for $28ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$. So we write $120ab^2\sqrt{2ac} - 28ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$ in the expanded form, we have 92 more  +ve $ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$ than -ve ones, so when we cancel -ve ones, we are left with 92 +ve ones which is same as $92ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$ when written in contracted form.

Answer (score 13):

Just view $ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$ as a separate entity.

As a matter of fact, let us use $d$ to represent it.

Then, we would have $120d-28d$, which is clearly $92d$.

Answer (score 8):

Observe that $\;120-28=92\;$ , and thus you have an expression of the form

$$120 K-28 K=92K\,.\;\text{In this case, we simply have}\;\;K=ab^2\sqrt{2ac}\;$$

Answer (score 5):

Although this question has several good answers and good points in the comments, I want to point out the explicit connection to the distributive law, in terms that can help in elementary school classrooms too.

Kids have little trouble answering the question

> If I have 7 apples and get 2 more how many do I have then?

If you want to write the answer with more formal mathematics (nowadays called a number sentence) it's

> 7 apples + 2 apples = 9 apples .

This principle helps kids master place value: think "hundreds" instead of "apples" and you get $700 + 200 = 900$, even $900 + 200 = 1100$.

You can even touch on the etymology of "ninety" as coming from "nine tens".

In the OP's question the unit quantity of which there are first 128 and then only 92 is $ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the site.

you have: 
$120ab^2\sqrt{2ac}-28ab^2\sqrt{2ac}$

What is the highest power of $a,b,c$ and rational numbers common to both terms?  Factor that out

$a: a\sqrt a\\
b: b^2\\
c: \sqrt c\\
\mathbb N: 4\\
4ab^2\sqrt{ac}(30 - 7)\\
4ab^2\sqrt{ac}(23)\\
92ab^2\sqrt{ac}$

Answer (score 3):

The $ab^2\sqrt{2ac} $ is a common factor between the two terms.

This means you can rewrite the whole expression as: $ ab^2\sqrt{2ac} (120 - 28) $.

Then you simplify what is inside the parenthesis and you get the answer your book has.